# How do I get data from a php file to another php file?

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to make a language file so a person who downloads the source code can change the text to there language. How do I get the text from one PHP file to another one?

This is the language.php file.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['home'] = "Home";
$_SESSION['about'] = "About";
$_SESSION['tools'] = "Tools";
$_SESSION['testing'] = "*Testing";
?>
```

This is the page I want the text to appear on, index.php

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start(); 
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Session</title>
</head>
<body>
    <font size="5">Testing <?php $_SESSION['home'] ?></font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Echo the data out. `<?php echo $_SESSION['home']; ?>`

Comment: you just forget ECHO <?php echo $_SESSION['home'] ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can save your all data in database and access it anywhere you want. Using session variables for this is not really a good idea...
You can also include your current file to the destination where you want to use the same data like:

```
include 'blah.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the result of session variable 'home' like this

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start(); 
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Session</title>
</head>
<body>
    <font size="5">Testing <?php echo $_SESSION['home']; ?></font>
</body>
</html>
```